# Convert Windows text file to Ubuntu text file

Tags: windows, windows-7, text

I am trying to port a C++ program from Windows to Ubuntu . In Ubuntu environment ,  My program reads a text file which was created in Windows , however it appears the  [Carriage Return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) is affecting the reading of the file in Ubuntu environment , therefore I wish to remove all the Carriage Return .

I have tried the following command on Windows to convert the text file to Linux format

```
dos2unix User.txt User1.txt
```

I also tried [this](https://kb.iu.edu/data/acux.html)

```
 tr -d '\15\32' < User.txt > User1.txt
```

Both these methods dont work , I am getting the following error :

```
is not recognised as an internal or external command , op program , or batch file
```

What am I doing wrong here ??

Comment: What text editor are you using in Ubuntu?

Comment: gedit text editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried the following command on Windows to convert the text file to Linux format

Try to run the commands **on your Ubuntu machine**. `tr` is in `coreutils` and therefore always available, `dos2unix` needs to be installed.

As a side note: In Python, a file object has the attribute *newlines*, that stores all end-of-line characters in a tuple. Is something similar available for C++?